# Second group of check boxes getting disabled by first group, but is not toggling correctly

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I read a lot of similar questions on SO, and I understand this question has been asked around  a lot. I have got the disabling part, and it works correctly. However, when I start unchecking checkboxes from either group, is when everything comes undone. Basically, When checkbox(es) of any group are click, the other group should be disabled.

This is my HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="printgroup"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="downgroup"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="printgroup"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="downgroup"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="printgroup"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="downgroup"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="printgroup"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="downgroup"></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the JS that disables either of the other group. I know the JS isnt the prettiest, perhaps you could help me make it better?

```
$(function(){
  $(".printgroup").click ( function() {
    if ( !$(this).is ( ":checked" ) )
    {
        $(".downgroup").removeAttr ( "disabled" );
        $('#printdown').attr('value', 'Go');
    }       
    else{
      $(".downgroup").attr ( "disabled" , true );
      $('#printdown').attr('value', 'Print');
    }
  });
});

$(function(){
  $(".downgroup").click ( function() {
    if ( !$(this).is ( ":checked" ) )
    {
        $(".printgroup").removeAttr ( "disabled" );
        $('#printdown').attr('value', 'Go');
    }       
    else{
      $(".printgroup").attr ( "disabled" , true );
      $('#printdown').attr('value', 'Download');
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetuxracer/wQfKz/) here.

EDIT: Should have persevered more. I solved the problem after a few minutes of posting.

I just replaced the `!$(this).is ( ":checked" )` to `!$('.downgroup').is ( ":checked" )` Still, the second part remains: han I make the JS efficient? I have two functions right now.  Can I reduce them to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could melt them together because they both do the same thing. Only the group is different. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wQfKz/2/.

```
$(".printgroup, .downgroup").on("click", function() {
    var isPrintGroup = $(this).is(".printgroup");
    var anyChecked = $(isPrintGroup ? ".printgroup" : ".downgroup").is(":checked");

    // disable other group depending on whether the current group has anything checked
    $(isPrintGroup ? ".downgroup" : ".printgroup").prop("disabled", anyChecked);

    if(!anyChecked) {
        $("#printdown").val("Go");
    } else {
        $("#printdown").val(isPrintGroup ? "Print" : "Download");
    }
});
```